# How to write mysql query to track today's records

Tags: php, mysql

i need to track opened,unopened and delivered emails by date. 
suppose i sent 5 emails yesterday but nothing opened yesterday and today again i sent another 5 emails so the total emails sent today =5. opened today =3(including yesterday's 2 and today's 1 email opened .still unopened 7 which is correct). But i need to display

today's unopened  mails count = today's sent mails- today's sent emails opened

Here is my db structure

```
ID ||| Email ||| Event |||  date**

1 ||| AAA  ||| Sent ||| 04-11-2015

2 ||| BBB  ||| Sent ||| 04-11-2015

3 ||| CCC  ||| Sent |||  04-11-2015

4 ||| DDD  ||| Sent ||| 04-11-2015

5 ||| EEE  ||| Sent||| 04-11-2015

6 ||| FFF  ||| Sent ||| 05-11-2015

7 ||| GGG  ||| Sent ||| 05-11-2015

8 ||| HHH  ||| Sent ||| 05-11-2015

9 ||| III  ||| Sent ||| 05-11-2015

I0 ||| JJJ  ||| Sent ||| 05-11-2015

11 ||| AAA  ||| Open ||| 05-11-2015

12 ||| BBB  ||| Open ||| 05-11-2015

13 ||| FFF  ||| Open ||| 05-11-2015
```

Comment: What identifies which email was sent yesterday but opened today ? Is that `Email` ?

Comment: i have unique email id,userid. email id is unique per day. i mean yesterday i sent 5 different emails tomorrow another new 5 mails will sent

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL `str_to_date` or `curdate` :-

```sql
Select Email,
    ((select count(*) from table
    where str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y')=curdate() and Event='Sent')
    -
    (select count(*) from table 
    where str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y')=curdate() and Event='Open')) as unopened 
From table limit 1
```

Comment: yes this query including 11,12 rows also. you can see those mails sent yesterday. but t need today's unopened which comes from today's sent - today's sent opened

Comment: you can see above table 6,7,8,9,10 rows were sent today and in those mails only 1 email opened which is 13

Comment: yes but you can see 11, 12 email subjects in above table. those were sent yesterday(1,2)

Comment: i want unopened from today's mails only

Comment: Select Email,
    ((select count(*) from table where 
    str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y')=curdate() and Event='Sent' group by Email)
    -
    (select count(*) from table 
    where str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y')=curdate() and Event='Open' group by Email)) as unopened 
From table limit 1

Comment: try this query @muralikalpana

Comment: subquery returning multiple rows

Comment: Select  ((select count(*) from ioi_track_stats where TO_DAYS(date_added) =TO_DAYS(NOW()) and event_type='delivered' group by camp_id,mail_id,variation_id,subscriber_id) - (select count(*) from ioi_track_stats where TO_DAYS(date_added) =TO_DAYS(NOW()) and event_type='opened' group by camp_id,mail_id,variation_id,subscriber_id)) as unopened From ioi_track_stats limit 1

Comment: is it possible to check it?

Comment: Select Email,
    ((select count(*) from table where 
    str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y')=curdate() and Event='Sent')
    -
    (select count(*) from table 
    where str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y')=curdate() and Event='Open' and Email not in
    (select Email from table where str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y')!=curdate() and Event='Sent')

    )) as unopened 
From table limit 1

Comment: Check this query @muralikalpana

Answer (score 0):

Today i sent these emails

FFF  ||| Sent ||| 05-11-2015

GGG  ||| Sent ||| 05-11-2015

HHH  ||| Sent ||| 05-11-2015

III  ||| Sent ||| 05-11-2015

JJJ  ||| Sent ||| 05-11-2015

On these emails opened only 1

FFF  ||| Open ||| 05-11-2015

So unopened 4 emails.

ofcourse these are opened today but these mails sent yesterday.

AAA  ||| Open ||| 05-11-2015

BBB  ||| Open ||| 05-11-2015

I want todays unopened= (today's sent)- (today's sent opened)

unopened = 5-1(today's sent email opened)

so total i will get 4.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch todays records using MySQL, you can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```